# conditional statement wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make a conditional statement for the excerpt on my index page.
If there is no manually excerpt I want the div that holds the excerpt to `dispaly:none`

```
<div class="excerpt"><?php if(!empty($post->post_excerpt)) {
     //This post have an excerpt, let's display it
     the_excerpt();
 } else {
     // <div class="excerpt" display:none?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use an inline if statement personally

```
<div class="exerpt" <?=((empty($post->post_excerpt)) ? 'style="display:none;"' : NULL)?> >
<?=the_exerpt()?>
</div>
```

So the html `style="display:none;"` only applies if `empty($post->post_exerpt)` is true

If you don't want to use an inline if statement you could do the following:

```
<?php
$style = NULL;
if(empty($post->post_exerpt()))
{
$style = ' style="display:none;" ';
}
?>
<div class="exerpt" <?=$style?> >
<?=$the_exerpt()?>
</div>
```

Although, why are you printing the `div` at all if it's just going to be hidden?

Why not:

```
<?php
if(!empty($post->post_exerpt()))
{
?>
<div class="exerpt">
    <?=$the_exerpt()?>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

that way the div is only added if there's content, if not, the div is ignored all together

Answer (score 1):

Just render the div differently in(line) of each case:

```
<?php if(!empty($post->post_excerpt)) {
    ?><div class="excerpt"><?php
    //This post have an excerpt, let's display it
    the_excerpt();
    ?></div><?php
} else {
    ?><div class="excerpt" style="display: none;" /><?php
} ?>
```

In this case you could also remove the `else` part, then it's just rendered if there is an excerpt and not even invisible.

Comment: This one is better because it doesn't call the_excerpt() unless necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="exerpt" style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="exerpt" <?php if(empty($post->post_excerpt)) { ?> style="display:none;" <?php }?> >
<?php the_exerpt()?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant think of any reasons why this shouldn't work. Unless you have a plugin that's creating manual excerpts. Sometimes search based plugins do that.

```
global $post
if(!empty($post->post_excerpt)) {
  the_excerpt();
} else {
  // whatever
}
```